# POST in SQL Server 2014 JSON data to Microsoft BI API

Tags: json, sql-server-2014, powerbi

I looking for a solution to POST JSON data to Microsoft BI API.

Or it's better to create a Windows Service application that POSTs data to BI instead of a daily SQL agent?

I found a solution:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1
RECONFIGURE

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[HTTP_POST]
@parameters NVARCHAR(max), @response NVARCHAR(max) OUTPUT
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
Declare @obj int,@hr int,@status int,@msg varchar(255),@sUrl varchar(2000)
set @sUrl = 'https://api.powerbi.com/'
exec @hr = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT

if @hr <> 0 begin Raiserror('sp_OACreate MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0
failed', 16,1) return end
exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @sUrl, false
if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Open failed' goto eh end
exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod setRequestHeader failed' goto
eh end
exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, send, NULL, @parameters
if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Send failed' goto eh end
exec @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'status', @status OUT
if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod read status failed' goto
eh
end
if @status <> 200 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod http status ' + str(@status) goto eh end
--exec @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @response OUT
--if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod read response failed' goto
--eh end
exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj
return
eh:
exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj
    Raiserror(@msg, 16, 1)
return
GO
```

Comment: Using a SP is a new way to me and I like it; but there seem to be many ways to go. I have used PowerShell scripts set as a Windows scheduled tasks, Azure Functions, Service Bus and, as you mentioned, console apps running as Windows services.